# How to insert ListBox into Grid?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want something like this: 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Hwp.png) 
And I try to use `ListBox`:

```
    <ListBox Name="lapsListBox">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding number}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding time}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But I can't align elements. How can I do it by another way?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <ListBox Name="lapsListBox">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding number}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding time}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

1. Remove the `Grid.Column="2"` from the Grid.
2. Place `HorizontalAlignment` of `Left` in the first column `Textblock`
3. I modified the Widths of the Columns to be "50%" each.